# Does training the in-built speech recogniser in windows improve the Microsoft Speech SDK engine?

Tags: c#, sdk, speech-recognition, training-data, language-packs

I have built a speech recognition demo in c# using the Microsoft Speech SDK from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378380(v=office.14).aspx

When creating a Speech recognition engine as in:-

```
using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
    new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")))
  {
```

In the constructor you can specify a culture, in this case it is a US English culture,  does this map to the in-built language packs which are installed in windows?.   I want to test whether training the speech recognition in windows with a language pack equal to that of this culture-info will improve my demo with other users of nationality but who speak English.